# Getting null value from Attendance Log table and Employee table using SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

I have the query to extract data like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.EmpName,
    d.DepartmentName,
    l.EnrollNumber,
    v.VerifyModeName,
    CAST(PunchTime as DATE)Check_Date,MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time))[TimeIN], MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))[TimeOUT],
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as Duration
FROM 
    Department d, 
    VerifyModes v, 
    Employee e 
FULL OUTER JOIN AttLog l 
    ON e.EnrollNumber=l.EnrollNumber
WHERE
    e.DeptID = d.Id
    AND l.VerifyMode = v.VerifyModeId 
GROUP BY 
    e.EmpName, d.DepartmentName, l.EnrollNumber, v.VerifyModeName, CAST(PunchTime as DATE)
ORDER BY Check_Date
```

The result is like this:

[image]

Although I've already included the `full outer join` condition.

If I only use:

```
select e.EmpName, l.PunchTime 
from Employee e 
full outer join AttLog l 
    on e.EnrollNumber = l.EnrollNumber
```

The result displays the `Employee` with `NULL` `PunchTime`:

[image]

So, how can I fix the above query to get the result that include `NULL` `PunchTime`?

Then, when I adding Date condition , the query still not display NULL again . How to correct it?

```
SELECT 
            e.EmpName,
            d.DepartmentName,
            l.EnrollNumber,
            v.VerifyModeName,
            CAST(PunchTime as DATE)Check_Date,MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time))[TimeIN], MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))[TimeOUT],
                RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
                RIGHT('0' + CAST((DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
                RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as Duration
        FROM Department d    
        INNER JOIN Employee e
            ON e.DeptID = d.Id
        LEFT JOIN AttLog l 
            ON e.EnrollNumber = l.EnrollNumber
        LEFT JOIN VerifyModes v
            ON l.VerifyMode = v.VerifyModeId 
        WHERE cast(l.PunchTime as Date) between '2015-07-22' and '2015-07-22'
        GROUP BY 
            e.EmpName, d.DepartmentName, l.EnrollNumber, v.VerifyModeName, CAST(PunchTime as DATE)

        ORDER BY Check_Date
```

[image]

Comment: Put the date comparison in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT 
    e.EmpName,
    d.DepartmentName,
    l.EnrollNumber,
    v.VerifyModeName,
    CAST(PunchTime as DATE)Check_Date,MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time))[TimeIN], MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))[TimeOUT],
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CAST(PunchTime as Time)), MAX(Cast(PunchTime as Time))) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as Duration
FROM Department d    
INNER JOIN Employee e
    ON e.DeptID = d.Id
LEFT JOIN AttLog l 
    ON e.EnrollNumber = l.EnrollNumber
LEFT JOIN VerifyModes
    ON l.VerifyMode = v.VerifyModeId 
GROUP BY 
    e.EmpName, d.DepartmentName, l.EnrollNumber, v.VerifyModeName, CAST(PunchTime as DATE)
ORDER BY Check_Date
```

---

Note: [Avoid using old-style `JOIN` syntax.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

---

Edit:
Instead of putting the date comparison in the `WHERE` clause, put it in the `JOIN` condition instead:

```
LEFT JOIN Attlog l
    ON e.DeptID = d.Id
    AND cast(l.PunchTime as Date) between '2015-07-22' and '2015-07-22'
```

Putting the comparison in the `WHERE` clause transforms the query into an `INNER JOIN` and thus dropping the `NULL` rows.

Comment: Please help if i adding Date condition for the query, it still not display who has NULL PunchTime

Comment: Put the DATE in the `JOIN` condition instead of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I replace WHERE by "JOIN cast(l.PunchTime as Date) between '2015-07-22' and '2015-07-22'"  but get the error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.